# java extract digits from string

Tags: java, regex, string

```
String str = "POLYGON((39.4189453125 37.418708616699824,42.0556640625 37.418708616699824,43.4619140625 34.79181436843146,38.84765625 33.84817790215085,39.4189453125 37.418708616699824))";
```

I have tried to get only `39.4189453125 37.418708616699824,42.0556640625 37.418708616699824,43.4619140625 34.79181436843146,38.84765625 33.84817790215085,39.4189453125 37.418708616699824`

with

```
final String coordsOnly = str.replaceAll("\\D\\(\\(\\w\\)\\)", "$2");
```

but i get `coordsOnly = "POLYGON((39.4189453125 37.418708616699824,42.0556640625 37.418708616699824,43.4619140625 34.79181436843146,38.84765625 33.84817790215085,39.4189453125 37.418708616699824))"`

what am i missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One reasonable approach here would be to match the following pattern and then replace all with the first capture group:

```
POLYGON\(\((.*?)\)\)
```

Sample code:

```
final String coordsOnly = str.replaceAll("POLYGON\\(\\((.*?)\\)\\)", "$1");
```

### Demo

**Edit:**

If you also need to isolate the pairs of numbers, you can just use `String#split()` on comma.  Actually, this looks like output from a database query, and I suspect that the database may offer a better way of getting out the individual values.  But the answers given here are an option for you in case you can't get the exact output you need already.

Comment: how can i make it more general so it will eliminate any leading word not just POLYGON ? I have tried `"(\\D)*\\(\\((.*?)\\)\\)"`

Comment: Use `str.replaceAll("\\w+\\(\\((.*?)\\)\\)", "$1")` ... [have a look at the updated demo](http://rextester.com/VFTTAS20862).  But note that in general it is better to make your regex more specific to avoid accidentally replacing the wrong text.

Comment: why has `.replaceAll("(\\D)*\\(\\((.*?)\\)\\)", "$2")` worked as well?

Comment: @EladBenda That says to replace any leading text which is not a digit (and capture it in `$1`).  Then the rest of the pattern is similar to what I have, capturing the content inside the double parentheses.  The second capture group `$2` is then used as the replacement, since the first one captured something else.  This approach is less efficient than what I proposed.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what you want?:

```
String rex = "[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(rex);
String input = "POLYGON((39.4189453125 37.418708616699824,42.0556640625 37.418708616699824,43.4619140625 34.79181436843146,38.84765625 33.84817790215085,39.4189453125 37.418708616699824))";
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(input);

while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: this one can match the whole part of expect string, (([0-9]+[.])[0-9]+[,]?\\s*)+

Comment: @yudongshen you should add that as an answer

Answer (score 2):

Actually, a lot.

```
"\\D" // Matches a non-digit character, but it only matches one,
      // while you need to match a word "POLYGON";
"\\(\\(" // Good. Matches the double left parentheses ((
"\\w"    // One word character? Same issue, you need to match multiple chars. And what about '.'?
"\\)\\)" // Good. Matches the double right parentheses ))
```

And escaped `()` doesn't create matching groups; and `\\w` matches only one word character `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`, it even won't match `.`.

I believe you should try something like this:

```
String coords = str.replaceAll("POLYGON\\(\\(([^)]+)\\)\\)", "$1");
```

Comment: How is this answer any different from what I posted 10 minutes before you did?

Comment: `"POLYGON\\(\\(([^)]+)\\)\\)"`  means that group-1 ends with `)` whileas `"POLYGON\\(\\((.*?)\\)\\)"` means kind of the same right? taking anything but the last two parans

Comment: Initially I was going with `[\d .,]+`, but then decided on the simpler version. Anyway, if we are only interested in finding the content between `(` and `)`, it would be faster to use `\\([^)]+\\)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this version:

```
str = str.replaceAll("[^\\d\\.\\s,]", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "POLYGON((39.4189453125 37.418708616699824,42.0556640625 37.418708616699824,43.4619140625 34.79181436843146,38.84765625 33.84817790215085,39.4189453125 37.418708616699824))";
String sp = "(([0-9]+[.])?[0-9]+[,]?\\s*)+";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(sp);
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(str);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

output:

> 39.4189453125 37.418708616699824,42.0556640625 37.418708616699824,43.4619140625 34.79181436843146,38.84765625 33.84817790215085,39.4189453125 37.418708616699824

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is replace all non-digit, space, dot or comma:

```
str.replaceAll("[\\D&&\\S&&[^,\\.]]", "")
```

Output:

```
39.4189453125 37.418708616699824,42.0556640625 37.418708616699824,43.4619140625 34.79181436843146,38.84765625 33.84817790215085,39.4189453125 37.418708616699824
```